# How to assign function output to an array type? In C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I try to assign to assign the output of a function to an array, but upon compiling, it doesn't seem to work.

The function `takeInputs` should return an array.  And, as I have it, I thought that `holdInputs` is an array.  However, it doesn't seem to compile.  What is the error here?

```
// Holds the expression that the user enters
struct Inputs  
{
    char word[10]; 
};

// Declare these: 
struct Inputs* takeInputs(struct Inputs *userInputs, int numInputs);  // must return a pointer to a pointer because returning array 
struct Inputs* printInputs(struct Inputs *userInputs);

struct Inputs* takeInputs(struct Inputs *userInputs,int numInputs){
    /*Inputs:
        userInputs: an array of struct Inputs, each of which contain a string called "word" 
        numInputs:  integer from user 
    */

    int i;
    for (i=0;i<numInputs;i++){
        printf("please input the word");        
        fgets(userInputs[i].word,10,stdin);
    }


}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

    //user Input should look like this:  ./takes_Input.exe 7
    if (argc!=2){
        error("user Input should look like this:  ./takes_Input.exe 7");
    }

    // represents the number of words the user is entering 
    int numInputs = atoi(argv[2]);

    struct Inputs allInputs[numInputs];
    struct Inputs holdInputs[numInputs];

    holdInputs = takeInputs(allInputs,numInputs);
    // printInputs(holdInputs);
    return 0;
}
```

Error output:

```
takes_Input.c: In function ‘main’:
takes_Input.c:53:13: error: assignment to expression with array type
  holdInputs = takeInputs(allInputs,numInputs);
```

But I thought I initialized holdInputs as an array??  Thanks.

Comment: You can't return an array from a function, period (§6.7.6.3, ¶1 _A function declarator shall not specify a return type that is a function type or an array
type_).  The nearest you can get is a pointer, and you'd have to arrange for the appropriate copying to be done.  You also can't assign arrays to each other; that's a major reason why functions such as `strcpy()` and `memmove()` exist.

Comment: `takeInputs` returns a pointer.

Comment: @immibis: except that it's not actually returning anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The function `takeInputs` should return an array. And, as I have it, I thought that `holdInputs` is an array. However, it doesn't seem to compile. What is the error here?

The error in this explanation is that a function can't return an array, as Jonathan Leffler pointed out in the comments.

---

> takes_Input.c:53:13: error: assignment to expression with array type
>     holdInputs = takeInputs(allInputs,numInputs);
>
> But I thought I initialized holdInputs as an array??

You did indeed declare `holdInputs` as an array, and it is an array. Though you haven't initialised it, that shouldn't be a problem. The error message is telling you that you can't assign to an array. For example,

```
char foo[4];
foo = "bar";        // This is an error
strcpy(foo, "bar"); // This is fine and dandy, like sour candy...
```

---

Or to take an example from your code, you're assigning to the array here:

```
holdInputs = takeInputs(allInputs,numInputs);
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
memcpy(holdInputs,takeInputs(allInputs,numInputs),numInputs*sizeof *allInputs);
```

Comment: So, I see what you're trying to do.  thank you.  However, that solution leads to an unkown error: ` C: Unknown error 2282780`

Comment: Moreover, memcpy just copies memory from one location to another.  `takeInputs` will still only return a single pointer, and not the entire array? so it isn't clear to me how this solves the problem?

Comment: If the problem is "*returning an array*" then you need to read this carefully: **You can't return an array**. A pointer is the best you can do. As for your error message, that seems like a suitable topic for your next question. Without seeing your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's difficult to say with certainty what the problem is, though from the *unknown*edness of it, I'd suggest that reinstalling your compiler and standard library might be the best option, perhaps checking for bit errors in your RAM if you commonly encounter instability whilst using your computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
// Holds the expression that the user enters
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Inputs  { char word[10]; };

// Declare these: 
__typeof__(struct Inputs (*)[]) takeInputs(struct Inputs (*userInputs)[], 
int numInputs);  // must return a pointer to a pointer because returning array 
void printInputs(struct Inputs (*userInputs)[]);

void printInputs(struct Inputs (*userInputs)[]){ 
        struct Inputs * ptr = *userInputs; 
        for(;*ptr->word != 0; ptr++){ 
                        printf("%s", ptr->word);
        }
}

__typeof__(struct Inputs (*)[]) takeInputs(struct Inputs (*userInputs)[], int numInputs){
/*Inputs:
    userInputs: an array of struct Inputs, each of which contain a string called "word" 
    numInputs:  integer from user 
*/

int i;
for (i=0;i<numInputs;i++){
               struct Inputs * ptr = (*userInputs+i);
               printf("please input the word\t");        
               fgets(ptr->word, 10, stdin);
      }
    return userInputs;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

//user Input should look like this:  ./takes_Input.exe 7
//if (argc!=2){
//    printf("user Input should look like this:  ./takes_Input.exe 7");
//    exit(1);
//}

// represents the number of words the user is entering 
//const char num[] = {4};
int numInputs = 7;//atoi(num);//atoi(argv[2]);

struct Inputs allInputs[numInputs];

/* this array pointer points to allInputs[] */
struct Inputs (*holdInputs)[numInputs];


holdInputs = takeInputs(&allInputs, numInputs);

printInputs(holdInputs);
return 0;
}
```